# There was an error compiling the function

Tags: vba, ms-access

When  i try to execute this function `PROD_TYPE: IIf([PROD_CAT]="OTHER";"OTHER";Mid([PROD_CAT];5))` I get compilation error message. I have tried to check if there was any missing reference i could uncheck but i found non.  the MID function seems to be the problem. because when i try to create a dummy query using MID function, it threw the same error message at me.

Comment: Can you show some of the PROD_CATs?  Is this vba or SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Access control sources do not accept semicolons when providing parameters, you need to use commas as you can see below:

```
IIf([PROD_CAT]="Other","Other",Mid([PROD_CAT],5))
```

Comment: i tried comma and the result is still the same. I always use semi colon which works for me. the problem seems to be the "MID" keyword.

Comment: @firmphem What datatype is `PROD_CAT` and could you give some data examples?

Comment: It is short text. the confusing thing is that i tried to execute the function in another access project by creating a dummy query and i worked fine

Comment: @firmphem And `PROD_TYPE` is short text as well?

Comment: This is typically caused by a reference marked MISSING. Go to the VBE window, menu _Tools, References_, and sort it out.

Comment: PROD_TYPE is a new header for the colum n that i want to create. yes it should be of the same datatype

Comment: @Gustav i coudnt find any missing reference

Comment: Then try a Compact & Repair.